# How to define loss function with XGBoost to only give confident answers?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, loss-function

I'm writing an XGBClassifier model with a custom loss function for a specific purpose.

### My Goal:

My dataset consists of data labeled in two classes: {-1, 1}. I want my model to output a prediction ***only when super confident*** about the class (I don't care if my model opts out of 99% of predictions). So, my approach is to let the model predict 0 (neutral) when not confident. Therefore:

- Data is labeled with values {-1, 1};
- Predictions should be values {-1, 0, 1};
- Majority of the predictions should theoretically be 0, given that the model is rarely super confident.

### Loss function I came up with:

```
loss = 0.02 + 0.06 * e^(-2.8 * y_pred * y_true)
```

- When `y_true = 1` the loss function [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYbwY.png);
- When `y_true = -1` the loss function [is inverted like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUfIF.png).

When model predicts neutral (0), the loss is intentionally nonzero so that the model is incentivized to make {-1, 1} predictions from time to time. I plan to play around with the numbers to get the model working best.

### Questions:

- Am I taking the correct approach to incentivize my XGB model to only give answers when confident?
- What do I do for this model to then output {-1, 0, 1}, because isn't the output naturally going to be in {-1, 1} because there weren't any {0} in the training set? Basically confused on how I would implement this.

This is what I've attempted.

```
def custom_loss(y_pred, y_true):
  grad = -0.168 * np.exp(-2.8 * y_true)
  hess = [0] * y_pred.shape[0]
  return grad, hess

model = xgboost.XGBClassifier(
    learn_rate=0.1,
    max_depth=3,
    n_estimators=5000,
    subsample=0.4,
    colsample_bytree=0.4,
    objective=custom_loss,
    verbosity=1
)

model.fit(
    X_train, 
    y_train, 
    early_stopping_rounds=100, 
    eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)], 
    verbose=True
)
```

It produces no change in the validation set accuracy. Definitely something wrong with my loss function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own loss function (as nice of an idea as that may be), you could also use the `XGBClassifier.predict_proba()` function that is described [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.predict_proba). This will provide you with an estimated "probability" (you should be careful to interpret it as a good estimate, as it is usually not well calibrated) that you can use to set the cutoff for yourself. This means you are in full control of the subsequent output step and you can freely set it to `{-1,0,1}` given the predicted probability, for example by choosing a threshold of 0.99 for a class `{-1,1}` to be predicted or otherwise output `0`. This is a simple yet not very sophisticated solution to your problem, if you want it.

Comment: Yeah I tried this earlier but unfortunately no valuable pattern. The accuracy goes all over the place so much that I'm better off using the raw predictions

Comment: If your accuracy (which might not be the important metric!) is "all over the place" - meaning low or varying a lot depending on the test set (?) -  you might have to look into that first. Nevertheless, the probabilities include this "prediction", since it only means choosing a threshold beyond which you decide for a class. So, you are basically always loosing information by letting the algorithm decide for you (I guess it just chooses 0.5?) and are never really "better off". You can have a look at the AUC-ROC to see how good your model does for all different thresholds. Is the data unbalanced?

Comment: I fixed the accuracy all over the place problem, found a bug in my data, now selecting top and bottom 1 percent of probabilities gives me much better accuracy than overall. I’m realizing that using the custom loss function I made is really no different from XGB’s default objective since both output a probability—they only differ in the penalty for each action. Still curious if there’s a better approach for this kind of problem. Data is cyclically unbalanced, best comparison I can make is stock market data. It is balanced in the long-run, but becomes unbalanced if you select a local time frame